# How to run ansible with aws dynamic inventory directly via GitHub Actions on ubuntu-latest?

Tags: ansible, github-actions, ansible-inventory

I've tryied with the following steps:

1. configured workflow in GitHub action:

```
name: Terraform-ansible-apply

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  Terraform:
    name: Terraform Plan & Apply
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Terraform Setup
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
        with: 
          terraform_wrapper: false

      - name: Terraform Init
        run: terraform init
        working-directory: ./Terraform

      - name: Terraform Validate
        run: terraform validate
        working-directory: ./Terraform

      - name: Terraform Apply
        id: tf-apply
        run: terraform apply -auto-approve
        working-directory: ./Terraform

################
  
      - name: install
        continue-on-error: true
        run: |
          pipx install boto3 --include-deps
          pipx install botocore --include-deps
      
      - name: Run Ansible playbook
        run: |
          ansible --version
          ansible-galaxy collection list
          ansible-inventory -i aws_ec2.yaml --graph
        working-directory: ./Ansible
```

but I get the following error:

```
Warning: :  * Failed to parse /home/runner/work/AWS-project/AWS-
project/Ansible/aws_ec2.yaml with
ansible_collections.amazon.aws.plugins.inventory.aws_ec2 plugin: Failed to
import the required Python library (botocore and boto3) on fv-az613-985's
Python /opt/pipx/venvs/ansible-core/bin/python. Please read the module
documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required
library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please
consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter
Warning: : Unable to parse /home/runner/work/AWS-project/AWS-
project/Ansible/aws_ec2.yaml as an inventory source
Warning: : No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
@all:
  |--@ungrouped:
```

In ansible.cfg I have the following enabled:

```
host_key_checking = False
remote_user=ubuntu
become=True
enable_plugins = aws_ec2
host_key_checking=False
```

Of course aws credentials are provided correctly via GitHub secrets.
Terraform code work perfect, the issue is with running ansible.

**Can you please assist what is missing? Or how it should be configured so ansible could run aws dynamic inventory **

```
ansible --version
  
ansible [core 2.15.1]
  config file = /home/runner/work/AWS-project/AWS-project/Ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/runner/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /opt/pipx/venvs/ansible-core/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/runner/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /opt/pipx_bin/ansible
  python version = 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0] (/opt/pipx/venvs/ansible-core/bin/python)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

Plugin file aws_ec2.yaml is the following:

```
plugin: aws_ec2
regions:
  - eu-central-1
```

amazon.aws collection is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding the following step to my job:

```
  - name: install additional dependencies for ansible which runs in venv
    run: |
      source /opt/pipx/venvs/ansible-core/bin/activate
      python -m pip install boto3
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to install the dependencies using [`pipx`](https://pypa.github.io/pipx/). This isn't doing you any good -- `pipx` installs each module into an isolated environment where it won't be visible to anything else.

Replace this:

```
- name: install
  continue-on-error: true
  run: |
    pipx install boto3 --include-deps
    pipx install botocore --include-deps
```

With:

```
- name: install
  run: |
    pip install boto3 botocore
```

(Note that I've intentionally removed `continue-on-error: true`, because it doesn't make any sense to continue on errors in this case -- if the dependencies don't install, your use of Ansible will fail.)

Comment: unfortunatelly it doesn't help, the output is the same

Comment: It's not clear from your question -- how are you installing Ansible?

Comment: I use GitHub hosted runner with: ubuntu-latest 
Ansible is already there, full specification for this docker is here:
https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md